# Low Power DC-AC Inverter

Tags: electromagnetic, induction, dc-ac

I'm searching for a schematic of a low power DC-AC inverter, to convert the output of USB, which is in DC to AC for **electromagnetic induction application**. I'm a self learner, I would like to know whether this whole idea is possible.

Also, do i need to step up the 5V of the USB to 12V? I did found some 12V to 110AC inverter circuit, however, they usually requires high power, 100W above.

I hope I'm clear with my question. Thank you in advance.

Comment: The question isn't at all clear. "Electromagnetic induction" could mean pretty much ANYTHING where a voltage is induced due to a changing magnetic field. And in practice, this means an infinite variety of applications and specifications. Nothing clear there, at all. It's just hand-waving. Being just as general, in reply, I'd just say the answer is "yes, the whole idea is possible." Also, "no, you don't have to step the voltage up to 12 V." For any specific suggestions, you'll need to be specific about the application details.

Comment: Bear in mind that depending on what your source is you either have 5V @ 0.1A (0.5W) or 5V @ 0.5A (2.5W) input power so you are not going to get much power out.  What output do you want?  Is a simple square wave OK, and what frequency and amplitude?

Comment: @jonk Ahh got it. Thanks for being patient with me. The entire project that I'm working on is to eliminate the usage of battery for **low power devices**, could be a mouse, or a tiny tabletop lamp that I found, which both only take up less than 0.5W individually. And I believe electromagnetic induction has to be the solution (but not the only and I purposely picked that), to improve mobility by eliminating the cable, at the same time still be able to operate with sufficient power from the USB.

I'm trying my best to structure my question once again. I hope the explanation helps you.

Comment: @WarrenHill yes I understand. Regarding the output, a simple square wave is preferable, and the frequency has to be high (for better efficiency), about 100khz to 300khz, and amplitude closer to the input voltage. I wasn't 100% sure about the output tbh, please let me know if I'm wrong.

Comment: @RickLee So. Do you want some kind of general purpose inverter that is limited to supporting \$\frac{1}{2}\:\textrm{W}\$ but that can supply any desired regulated voltage so long as the current compliance follows the power limitation? If so, that's a rather fancy 'battery eliminator' device. Or do you have some limitations on the output voltages needed?

Comment: @jonk I don't think "battery eliminator" is the right one after looking it up. I'm searching for a basic inverter that can convert a constant DC voltage (let's say 5V 0.5A), to a square-wave AC voltage thus I can use the output to perform wireless power transfer(WPT) , as WPT requires AC voltage as input. The only limitation I can think of is the frequency, it has to be high (about 100khz).

Comment: @RickLee Well, WPT just narrows it down to inductive coupling, microwave, light/lasers, magnetodynamic coupling, capacitive coupling, resonant coupling, and... well... I'm going go hold off. Not narrow enough for my tastes. Perhaps someone else can guess.